# Would this be a valid way of running a loop in c++?

Tags: c++, loops, syntax, while-loop

If I want to have a while loop: while a variable does NOT equal several different values, is this valid?:

```
while (uInput != ('a' || 'b' || 'c')){
    //do something to make it equal one of those
}
```

Or would I have to individually compare uInput to a, uInput to b, and so on?

Comment: Did you try to compile this yourself?

Comment: This has been asked a million times, and answered a million times, most notably towards the beginning of your C++ book. Which one are you using?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It doesn't do what you want it to do. You need to compare to each value individually:

```
uInput != 'a' && uInput != 'b' && uInput != 'c'
```

As it is, `('a' || 'b' || 'c')` would be evaluated to `true` and the expression becomes equivalent to:

```
uInput != true
```

Comment: @M.M. Hm, I suppose that depends on how you interpret what they're trying to do. But you're probably right.

Comment: Write an incorrect answer, then plagiate the correct one to get to the top. Way to go.

Comment: @DarkWanderer I corrected my answer based on a comment that has now been deleted. It was just a different interpretation of what exactly the asker was looking for. I didn't give myself the votes and I'm really sure Andy couldn't care less.

Answer (score 3):

**No**. What you want to write is:

```
while ((uInput != 'a') && (uInput != 'b') && (uInput != 'c'))
{
    //do something to make it equal one of those
}
```

The expression `('a' || 'b' || 'c')` would be evaluated by converting the characters `'a'`, `'b'`, and `'c'` too `bool`; actually, *only the first operand* (`'a'`) gets evaluated here, since its evaluation yields value `true` and guarantees that the whole expression `('a' || 'b' || 'c')` evaluates to `true` as well - short-circuiting is applied.

So what your initial loop does is:

```
while (uInput != true)
{
    //do something to make it equal one of those
}
```

Which is unlikely what you want.

Comment: Thanks I was just making sure.

Answer (score 3):

### No.

> Would this be a valid way of running a loop in c++?

It's "valid", but it doesn't do what you wanted it to do. Unlike me, the compiler won't magically deduce your intention, as it differs from the semantics of the language.

The `!=` operator is dumb, in that it doesn't care what funny magic you're trying to do on the right-hand-side of it — the *result* of that right-hand-side expression is what gets compared, and the result of `('a' || 'b' || 'c')` is just one value *i.e.* not a list of options, as you'd intended.

Some languages provide alternative operators that *do* allow you these semantics, e.g. in SQL:

```sql
SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE NOT value IN ('a', 'b', 'c')
--                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

But even in SQL the basic inequality operator does not care about lists:

```sql
SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE value != ('a', 'b', 'c')
-- probably a syntax error, or otherwise failure to do what you wanted
```

In C++ you *only* get the dumb syntax, though if you really wanted to you could place those options inside a container (such as an `std::vector`) and use an algorithm such as `std::find`:

```c++
std::vector<char> v{'a', 'b', 'c'};
while (std::find(uInput, v.begin(), v.end()) != v.end()) {
  // ...
}
```

Of course, this is way over the top when all you want to do is write:

```c++
while (uInput != 'a' && uInput != 'b' && uInput != 'c')
```

Comment: Also, Pascal has `in` keyword to do this. I remember something like `if x in ['a','b','c'] then ...`

Answer (score 1):

The correct answer is

```
while (uInput != 'a' && uInput != 'b' && uInput != 'c')
```

Because the condition

```
uInput != 'a' || uInput != 'b' || uInput != 'c'
```

will always evaluate to true, even if uInput is equal to one of the values, making your loop an infinite one.

You really need to read about C++ syntax.